# Защита от одновременного редактирования

Tags: c#, sql-server

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста. Работаю в  Winforms. Есть таблица

```
Sotrudniki (поля id_sotrud, imya, familiya, data_rojd, pol )
```

Есть Форма Редактирования текущей информации-`FormUserInfoEdit`. Приложение предполагает многопользовательский доступ. Как предотвратить, что бы одна и та же запись в один момент не редактировался несколькими пользователями?

Например, информация  Сотрудника у которого `id_sotrud =3` в один и тот же момент может редактировать несколько пользователей. Как сделать если первый пользователь начал редактировать , программа должна предупредить второму пользователю , что текущая запись редактируется другим пользователем. Если не затруднит вас, покажите в виде кода.

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает. что эту задачу нужно решать на стороне сервера, и не важно какой будет при этом клиент. я уже основательно забыл SQL, но там вроде должны быть блокировки для таблиц и/или отдельных  записей на время транзакции.

Comment: запись из базы надо прочитать чем то вроде `Select * From Table With (UpdLock, NOWAIT) Where ID=1` По идее это должно вернуть ошибку "запись заблокирована" любому, кто попытается ее читать так же. Но с этим надо быть аккуратным, человек может открыть запись в редакторе и уйти на обед и все это время никто не получит к ней доступа на запись

Comment: @Mike а если как в некоторых текстовых редакторах сделать - чтение без блокировок, редактирование тупо в форме, с периодической проверкой, что данные не изменились. Если изменились - перечитать прямо в режиме редактирования. По подтверждению окончания редактирования - запрос на обновление с кратковременной блокировкой. Так получится?

Comment: @rdom Обновление в любом случае автоматически возьмет блокировку до окончания транзакции. Думаю стоит оценить возможность такого события. На основании чего меняются данные в таблице, возможно на основании неких первичных документов, какова вероятность что первичные документы касающиеся одной записи окажутся у двух вводящих информацию в базу. И кстати, некоторые системы отслеживают какие именно поля изменились и посылают update с указанием в SET только этих полей, что минимизирует возможные коллизии. Правда если платформа не дает готового решения - это довольно муторно самому делать.

Comment: Мне приходилось работать в системе с пессимистической блокировкой (давным давно, TestTrackPro) и это было **ужасно**. Особенно радовали ситуации, когда сотрудник ставил лок на баг (просто открывая его детали) и уходил на обед. Или на ночь домой. Или в отпуск. И manager-а с правом снять блокировку под рукой не было. Насколько бы хорошей вам не казалась идея "запретить редактирование", пожалуйста, не реализуйте ее :)

Comment: @PashaPash: С другой стороны, оптимистическая блокировка означает либо потерю данных, введённых юзером при редактировании, либо очень умный автормёрдж. И то, и другое не очень хорошо, особенно для нетехнического пользователя.

Answer (score 6):

*Это более-менее независимая от используемых технологий штука. Подумайте, можете ли применить её в этом случае.*

Можно реализовать обычный [CAS (Compare-And-Swap)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC) (*идею*, а не саму операцию): он **не предотвратит одновременного редактирования**, но позволит *обнаружить* ситуации, когда конфликты всё же происходят.

Идея проста: заводим поле **версии** (момент последнего изменения, например) и заставляем клиента в момент посылки сообщать, какую версию записи он, собственно, изменял.

- Если в базе то же значение **версии**, то всё в порядке, конфликта нет. Обновляем поле версии новым значением и сохраняем данные.
- Если значение версии с тех пор изменилось, то запись кем-то была изменена во время редактирования и при сохранении новой версии изменения прошлого редактора(-ов) будут утеряны. **Конфликт.**

В случае конфликта сделать следующее:

1. Отказать в сохранении.
2. Отобразить, что в базе прямо сейчас и какой оно версии (опционально, можно также показать исходное состояние, вокруг которого возник конфликт, дав пользователю выполнить т. н. "3-way merge").
3. Дать пользователю поправить свои изменения из предположения, что теперь он редактирует новую версию (согласно п. 2 он должен её как минимум видеть).
4. Вернуться к началу (при сохранении проверить, не произошёл ли конфликт снова).